# How can i make the track to constraint track on x axis using location transformation instead of rotation?

Tags: tracking

When i move my bone that i assigned to the eyes of my character using track to constraint they will track up and down but only will track side to side when i rotate the bone. is there any way to make them both transformation in location?

Answer (score 0):

You would almost certainly prefer a damped track.  Here's an example:

[image]